# Express.js - res.render and redirect at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications, routes

I am building a web app, including routes for authentication.

**The Problem:** When a registration succeeds I want to **redirect** to `/login`, but also include render options. But when I **render** the `login.ejs` the url stays `/register`.

**The Options:** I either have to find a way to use `res.render` and change the url *OR* use `res.redirect` and also pass render variables.

This is minimal code to show my problem:

```
app.get("/login", (res, req) => {
 res.render("login.ejs", {flag: ""})
}

app.post("/register", (res, req) => {
  // registration logic
  if(success) {
    res.render("login.ejs", {flag: "registration_success"})
  } 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect in expressjs while passing some context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035373/how-do-i-redirect-in-expressjs-while-passing-some-context)

Comment: Similar question/answer here [Redirecting from one route to another with data from first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162321/is-there-any-way-of-redirecting-from-one-route-to-another-with-data-from-first-r/51162748#51162748).

Answer (score 0):

the url shown is what you write in `app.post("/someURL"` not what you redirect to.

so if u want to redirect to login page after successful registration, simply redirect to `"/login"`. it renders `"login.ejs"`

about the part that you probably want to show a sign up success message, u can use `'flash'` package; it helps you add data to memory and get it in client side and show a success message. I use sweetalert2 in such a way:

in back-end code:

```
req.flash('a-name-you-want', { flags, you, want });
```

to get these info in front-end:

```
<% let yourData = req.flash('the-name')
if(yourData.length) {
  // do sth to the data
}%>
```

I hope it helped you!